# How were the cathode rays concluded to be made of "particles"?

Tags: experimental-physics, electrons

I have read about the Cathode Ray experiments which through varying the conditions led to the conclusion that those "rays" had negative charge and even we calculated the specific charge of its constituents.

But I don't exactly get how they **"quantised"** those rays ? Like *it could have been some sort of a continuous "fluid" (just an analogy) or a "wave" of negative charge*. So what led to the conclusion of its **"particle" make up ?**

Answer (score 2):

*So what led to the conclusion of its **particle** make up?*
It was a gradual evolving process.

Not knowing what they were cathode rays were given their name because they originated on the cathode of a discharge tube and formed shadows like other waves.
The measurement of the specific charge of cathode rays by Thomson  (1897) was a crucial piece of evidence of their particle nature in that in his experiments he also found that cathode rays were deflected by both magnetic **and** electric fields.

At that time there was no Quantum Mechanics and the idea that cathode rays were particles was consistent with the current laws of Physics as no known waves were deflected by electric and/or magnetic fields. Thomson also observed that the specific charge of the cathode rays was always the same regardless of the makeup (material of cathode and gas in tube) of the discharge the tube which gave him that idea that all cathode rays were of the same type.
Kaufmann (1901) showed that the specific charge of cathode rays was dependent of the speed of the cathode rays consistent with Einstein's theory of special relativity (1905).

Measurements by Millikan (1909) of the charge on one of the charged particles (electron) resulted in a value for the mass of an electron being found.
Conclusive proof the cathode rays were made up of a stream of particles?
But then Davison and Germer (1927) were the first to show the wave nature of electrons. . . .

Comment: Can you give some info on how (& when) it was discovered that the cathode ray particles are the same as the particles that carry charge in a typical electrical circuit?

Comment: @PM2Ring [History of Electricity](https://www.explainthatstuff.com/history-of-electricity.html) might answer your question? or ask as a separate question.

Comment: @PM2Ring Modern version of [Perrin tube 1895](https://spark.iop.org/perrin-tube-sign-electron-charge)

Comment: I was hoping you'd add that info to your answer. ;) https://www.explainthatstuff.com/history-of-electricity.html#source mentions George Johnstone Stoney's electricity particle theory of 1874, but it doesn't explain how it was decided that the cathode ray particles found by Thomson in 1897 are, in fact, Stoney's electrons.

Comment: OTOH, I suppose the OP is only asking about cathode rays, and is not concerned about them being the same as the electrons flowing in a circuit, so there's no *need* for your answer to address that.

Comment: @PM 2Ring i have been taught that it was the similarity of specific charge that led to the conclusion that all such things was actually the electron..